# Is 'Seamster' a gender-specific noun?

Tags: nouns, suffixes, gender-neutral, agent-noun-suffix

At first, I thought *seamster* is a word used to address a male person who sews clothes and *seamstress* is used to address a female sewer. But there are different explanations online. [FineDictionary](http://www.finedictionary.com/seamster.html) and [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seamster) describe *seamster* as a gender-neutral noun.

If these descriptions are correct, what is the male version of *seamstress*?
 Can someone throw light on this topic?

Comment: As with [many other words](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/123381/191178) (for example: actor, actress), the "masculine" form of the word can be used for either gender. But in this case, the word "tailor" is probably the best; the other terms seem antiquated to me.

Comment: @Laurel, the word tailor is also gender-neutral. Check [this][1] [1][https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/132817-Is-the-word-quot-tailor-quot-used-for-both-men-and-women]

Comment: Some feminine forms of occupational words have long since fallen out of use, e.g. authoress (because it's no longer seen as unusual for a woman to write books). Others, such as actress, are beginning to fall out of use. Seamstress used to be a common word because that type of sewing was traditionally done by women (as distinct from tailoring or sailmaking, done by men). In these days of more gender equality, it would seem quite reasonable to use 'seamster' for both.

Comment: @Balu_Madaraju I know it's gender neutral. We don't need to have gender specific words; this fact is reflected in occupational titles that have only been invented recently (programmer, for example).

Comment: @Laurel, "We don't need to have gender specific words": that sounds so  convincing & comfortable :) But they're not obsolete yet.

Comment: I have never ever encountered the word _seamster_; but historically _-ster_ was usually a feminine suffix anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seamstress](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/seamstress)  is the term that is still used:

> - a woman who can sew and make clothes or whose job is sewing and making clothes. (OLD)

It derives from ***[seamster](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/seamster)***, which is gender-neutral but also quite rare ( [see Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seamster%2C%20seamstress&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseamster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseamstress%3B%2Cc0) ):

> ***seamstress (n.):***
>
> - 1640s, with -ess + seamster (also sempster), from Old English seamestre "sewer, tailor, person whose work is sewing," from seam. ***Originally indicating a woman, but after a while the fem. ending -estre no longer was felt as such and a new one added.***
>
> (Etymonline)

Answer (score 1):

Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings* (2002), part of the Oxford Paperback Reference series, has this say about the suffix *-ster*:

> **-ster** *A person or thing associated with a an activity or quality.* {Old English *-estre*, *-istre*, etc.}
>
> Early examples referred to a woman engaged in an occupation, such as ***brewster***, ***maltster***, and ***spinster***, this last originally 'a woman who spins' (the ending was the feminine equivalent of words ending in *-ere*, which later became *-er*; [cross reference omitted]. It has long been extended to activities undertaken by men such as ***chorister*** or ***teamster***. Words in which it refers to a characteristic of the person include ***youngster*** and the US-derived ***oldster***, as well as ***hipster*** (a person who is *hip*, who follows the latest trends and fashions). Less often, the ending refers to objects, ***roadster*** being a rare example.
>
> It often has a derogatory sense: ***tipster***, ***rhymester***, ***prankster***. Many of these are more common in the US than in Britain: ***gamester***, ***gangster***, ***huckster***, ***jokester***, ***mobster***, ***punster***, ***trickster***. Such terms continue to be formed , again most frequently in the US: ***popster***, ***hypester***, ***soulster***, ***scamster***.
>
> *Master* comes from Old English *mæg(i)ster*, but derives from Latin *magister* (*see also* -MEISTER; others that derive from from Latin words with the same ending include *minister* and *barrister* (formed from *bar* in imitation of *minister*), as do nouns ending in -ASTER (such as *poetaster*). In words such as *boaster*, *jester*, *broadcaster*, and *protester* the suffix is *-er* ... on a stem ending in *st*.

Joseph Shipley, *Dictionary of Word Origins* (1945) offers a similar discussion of *-ster* in his entry for *spinster*, although he alludes to the form *sempster*, rather than *seamster*:

> **spinster.** Obviously, one that spins. But it is the suffix that has the story. Originally, it was feminine only, and was applied in occupations once carried on by women—since taken over by men, and the words lost, though some of them re preserved as names, *e.g.*, *Baxter*, from *bakester*, of which the masculine given name was *Baker*. As men did the work, some of the words had a second feminine suffix added, to indicate women: *sempster*, whence *sempstress*; *songster*, whence *songsteress*. Applied to men, the suffix usually indicates inferiority (*rhymester*) or other bad traits (*punster*, *gangster*, *trickster*); this is even more apparent in the LL. form of the suffix (which is originally the combination of Sansk. —*as*— —*tar*); *poetaster*. (*Minister*, *magistrate*, are formed with the Sansk. comparative suffixes —*yans*— —*tara*; *cp.* *month*: May.)

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) confirms the gist of Quinion's (and Shipley's) analysis as it applies to *seamster*:

> **seamster** n {ME *semester*, *semster*, fr. OE *sēamestre*, seamstress, tailor, fr. *sēam*, seam (bef. 12c) : a person employed in sewing; esp: TAILOR.}

The *Eleventh Collegiate* also has an entry for *seamstress*:

> **seamstress** *n* (1598): a woman whose occupation is sewing.

The upshot of these discussions is that *seamster/sempster* was itself originally a gender-specific term, the gender being female, and that when the term began to lose its gender specificity, it was feminized a second time to *seamstress* when a woman was intended. This left *seamster/sempster*, by default, as a neutral or vaguely male term—but note that the term did not shift to *seamer*, on the pattern of *brewster* (to *brewer*) or *bakester* (to *baker*). Thus, one might argue that etymologically *seamster* is actually a less gender-specific term than, say, *brewer* or *baker*.

However, such an argument fails to acknowledge the effect that the existence of *seamstress/sempstress* has on the situation. Because a clearly female-specific term exists, the alternative term takes on a masculine implication that it objectively doesn't have. Similarly, although men and women can be actors or poets, the existence of *actress* and *poetess* as female-specific terms implies a maleness to the unfeminized term that, objectively, isn't there. But unlike *actor/actress* and *poet/poetess*, *seamster/seamstress* and *sempster/sempstress* are pairs in which the emphatically female-specific form is far more common than the the neutral or quasi-male-specific form, as this Ngram chart of *seamster* (blue line) versus *seamstress* (red line) versus *sempster* (green line) versus *sempstress* (yellow line) for the period 1720–2008 makes clear:

[image]

In the modern world, it is difficult to see why the gender of the person pursuing an occupation should be relevant to the form of the word use to characterize him or her as a person engaged in that occupation. But given that the female-specific *seamstress* dominates the field of usage in the *seamster/seamstress/sempster/sempstress* bundle of terms, *seamster* seems rather poorly positioned to point the way to a gender-neutral future. In the long term, I think, it is more likely that the entire group of *seamster/seamstress/sempster/sempstress* terms will gradually drop out of use in favor of gender-neutral use of *tailor*. Nevertheless, as the Ngram chart above indicates, *seamstress* has actually become considerably more frequent in the Google Books database over the past 50 years, and it is not impossible that female-specific *seamstress* and gender-neutral or quasi-male-specific *seamster* will remain in use indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

A tailor is a very skilled person. Not equivalent to a seamster at all. Seamster is gender neutral. A woman can also be a tailor or a seamstress.